# delaying ajax or jquery call until dynamic image loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Ajax wait until all images are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774746/jquery-ajax-wait-until-all-images-are-loaded)

```
//var imgURL="http://xxxx.xxx:8084/xxx/largedynamicimagethattakestime
FB.api(
    '/me/photos', 
    'post', 
    {
        message:' coffee',
        url: imgURL        
    }, 
    function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured'+response.error);
        } 
        else {
            //...........
        }
    }
);
```

I want to launch this `fb.api` call only when `var imgURL` completes loading.
is there any way so that I can load this image in a `div` and make a call to `fb.api` only when the image gets completely loaded?
providing a button with image to post this images is also welcomed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the image's onload event:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = function() {
    // Call API
};

image.src = "http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Scitech/660/371/tardar-sauce-the-cat.jpg";

document.body.appendChild(image);
```