# Wait until content loaded by .html() is ready

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where I use the jquery `.get()` method to load in contents and `.html()` to display them on my page. During the loading process I have a div box with a preloader positioned above my page to hide the new elements popping up and instead display a gif. 
Some pages take very long to load though, as there are iframes, pictures etc included in them. Now I only want the preloader div to be removed after everything has been fully loaded, which is where I can't find an answer, as there is no `.html()` callback function.
I've tried `.load()`, `.on()` with load as an event, the `.done()` function on the `.get()` method but nothing seems to work as I would like to have it.

Is there any chance to find out, when the the contents of my ajax div have finished loading, so I can then remove the preloader?

**Edit**
This is my HTML Markup

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="ajax_cont">
<!-- The content will come in here -->
</div>
<div class="preloader"></div>
</div>
```

Maybe I didn't explain the problem clear enough, so here is my js code as well:

```
function load_ajax(linktofile) {
    $(".preloader").fadeIn(200);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $.get("ajax/" + linktofile, function(data){}).done(function(data) {

            var content = $(data).filter('#loaded_content').html();

            $(".ajax_cont").html(content); //It takes a while until all pictures, which were included in content, are fully loaded in .ajax_contnt          

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".preloader").fadeOut(200); //I want this to be executed only when everything is fully ready
            }, 150);

        });
    }, 200);    
}
```

I've added a few comments to clarify, what exactly I meant.

Comment: `.done()`  wont fire until after your ajax has completed.

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: put the preloader inside the html which is going to be replaced, so the ajax call will replace the preloader when it is completed

Comment: I've added my html to the question. .done() wont work for me, as it waits for the ajax call to finish and not the content to be loaded completely. And if I replace the preloader then it disappears to early as well.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately this didn't do the trick either. The problem isn't that it doesn't wait until the ajax request is completed, this works flawless. The thing is that I would like to wait until the new content inside `.ajax_cont` is completely ready (iframes, pictures etc) until `.preloader` fades out.

Comment: This answer might provide the solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17989377/2788872

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // assuming .loader is a button/link to load content
  // and .preloader is the window (overlay) that will show while content is being loaded
  $('.loader').click(function(){

    // fadein
    $('.preloader').fadeIn(200);

    // load content
    $('.ajax_cont').load("ajax/" + linktofile,function(){

       // use jquery's **:last** to wait for the last image to load then fadeout
       $('.ajax_cont img:last').on('load',function(){
          $('.preloader').fadeOut(200);
       });

    });  // ajax_cont load
  });  // loader click
});  // document ready
```