# Preloader in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've coded a fancy preloader with jQuery for my project. While my AJAX query is processed it is activated.

I have used to load it:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function) () {
    #preloder is displayed 
}
```

And to stop it:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function) () {
    #preloder is turned off 
}
```

Problem is my AJAX returns images `src` that are then diplayed in a `<div>` but some of the pictures are really heavy and most of the time my preloader stops before my pictures are completely loaded.

I went through jquery documentation and found a .load(function). But it seems that it has been removed from jQuery. It seems that it has been replaced by `.trigger("load")`. Can it be useful for my problem? I tried to implement it but with no sucess.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774746/jquery-ajax-wait-until-all-images-are-loaded

Comment: Would this do the trick?   `$('img').on('load', function() {
      // do something
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer from @Aureliano Far Suau that worked beautifully for me. No plugin needed:

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
          // do something
    });
```

For multiple images:

```
var loaded = 0;
$('img').on('load', function() {
   loaded++;
   if(loaded == $('img').length){
      // do something
   }
});
```